# Query from Redis depending on key value

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

I need to write a node js application which will connect to REDIS based on a key and then update the key as per latest timestamp. This timestamp will be a property which will be present as the value of the key. 
For e.g. client.set(key,object) , where **key -- productId** and 
**object -- 
{ 

"productName" : "abc", 

"make" : "abc",

"expiry" : "abc",

"timestamp": "333333"
}** 
Is there any way where in I can get the timestamp and check if it is the latest or not and then update the record.I am currently using **ioredis library** with cluster feature